# When is a reference being 'used' in non-lexical lifetimes?

Tags: rust

```rust
struct Object {
    alive: bool,
    name: String,
}

impl Object {
    // the comments are what I thought the compiler was supposed to give
    fn test(&mut self) {
        let alive = &mut self.alive; // seems like there is mutable borrow here
        self.name = String::from("dead"); // another mutable borrow
        *alive = false; // mutable borrow later used here
    }
}

fn print(x: &Object) {
    println!("Hello {:?}", x);
}
```

A non-lexical lifetime is supposed to be when a reference stops living after it's last use. I am confused on what that use is.

`alive` is a mutable borrow to `self.alive` and then `self` is used to do `self.name = String::from("dead");`. After this it looks like alive is used again in `*alive = false`. Except this code compiles.

If I change the code to this:

```rust
    fn test(&mut self) {
        let alive = &mut self.alive;
        print(self);
        self.name = String::from("dead");
        *alive = false;
    }
```

then the code gives this error

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable                                                                 [10/58]
  --> src/main.rs:45:15                                                                                                                                        
   |                                                                                                                                                           
44 |         let alive = &mut self.alive;                                                                                                                      
   |                     --------------- mutable borrow occurs here                                                                                            
45 |         print(self);                                                                                                                                      
   |               ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
46 |         self.name = String::from("dead");
47 |         *alive = false;
   |         -------------- mutable borrow later used here
```

. Does this mean that references are only 'used' when they are in functions and not when dereferenced with * or the dot notation? How does the first example compile even though it seems like the the reference scopes are overlapping?

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that references are only 'used' when they are in functions and not when dereferenced with * or the dot notation?

You are close. Non-lexical lifetimes aren't a factor here, but the borrow checker has more tricks up its sleeves. It knows that the *fields* of a struct are distinct objects and can be borrowed independently.

From the Rust Nomicon on [Splitting Borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html):

> It does understand structs sufficiently to know that it's possible to borrow disjoint fields of a struct simultaneously. So this works today:
>
> ```
> struct Foo {
>     a: i32,
>     b: i32,
>     c: i32,
> }
>
> let mut x = Foo {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0};
> let a = &mut x.a;
> let b = &mut x.b;
> let c = &x.c;
> *b += 1;
> let c2 = &x.c;
> *a += 10;
> println!("{} {} {} {}", a, b, c, c2);
> ```

So in your code, there can be exclusive references to both `self.alive` and `self.name` because borrow checker knows they aren't referencing the same object. Adding the `print(self)` needs to reference the whole `self` and conflicts with the borrow given to `alive`.